# Find run with specific text in it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, openxml, docx

I have this to find runs with text that starts with #, but I get an empty sequence back:

```
IEnumerable<Run> runs = doc.Descendants<Run>().
     Where<Run>(r => r.Descendants<Text>().First<Text>().Text[0] == '#');
```

This cannot be right because the following gives me 4 results:

```
IEnumerable<Text> t = doc.Descendants<Text>().
       Where<Text>(txt => txt.Text[0] == '#');
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I see that, but I have runs with ONLY the #-text...

Comment: I've moved my comment to an answer now. I suspect you'll find there are some text elements you weren't expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Well your first snippet only gives runs whose first text descendant starts with #. Your second snippet gives all text descendants starting with #. So if you've got any runs with a non-first text descendant starting with #, that will be counted in the second snippet but not the first...

It's unclear which behaviour you actually want, but if you *do* want to find every run containing a text element starting with `#`, just change your first snippet to:

```
IEnumerable<Run> runs = doc
    .Descendants<Run>()
    .Where<Run>(r => r.Descendants<Text>()
                      .Any<Text>(text => text.Text[0] == '#'));
```

If you're still surprised that the two snippets give you different results, you could easily check that:

```
foreach (var run in doc.Descendants<Run>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Run!");
    foreach (var textElement in run.Descendants<Text>())
    {
        string text = textElement.Text;
        Console.WriteLine("- {0}", text.Substring(0, Math.Min(5, text.Length)));
    }
}
```

(I haven't used this object model for a long time, by the way - so you should also check whether there are things like nested runs.)

Comment: Indeed your solution works. thnx. still: I do have runs with only ...etc. Anyway...

Comment: @Erik: So if you think your first piece of code should have worked, run the diagnostic code at the end of my answer and you should be able to see why it didn't.